# How to render django-allauth templates

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, templates, django-allauth

I could not understand as to why my django-allauth templates are not able to be rendered. I copied allauth directory to my project. I also have a bootstrap-themed catalog app which should be displayed after login. I expect signup and login forms from django-allauth to be displayed, and after login subsequently redirect to rendering bootstrap-themed catalog app's templates.

In settings.py, among other required apps, I have added django-allauth modules after the catalog app in INSTALLED_APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS=['catalog',
            'allauth',
            'allauth.account',
            'allauth.socialaccount',
]
```

Added Authentication Backends as:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)
```

In settings.py , templates directory is set as:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'allauth/templates/account'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'catalog/templates/catalog')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'allauth.account.contextprocessors.account',
                'allauth.socialaccount.contextprocessors.socialaccount',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'ecomstore.utils.context_processors.ecomstore',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I let django-allauth which url to route to when login is successful. Add `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'`

Set the url routing in myproject as:

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),             
    ]
```

As indicated above, my question is why are django-allauth templates not rendered?

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: @AstikAnand There is no "error" messages, except the template displayed should be login and signup forms from django-allauth, not the project (bootstrap) template that stems from catalog app.

Comment: Maybe then template names are clashing try changing the template name of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a few thing:
in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
'django.contrib.sites',
```

After that add a line with

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

If it still does not work when you put these in there might be an issue with the order which apps are loaded.

Allauth also comes with its own login, logout and change passwords see [here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html)

If you are switching out templates you can put the allauth templates in by using tags like:

```
{% url 'account_login' %} <!-- Sign In-->
```

and if you need check if users have signed in you can used an if statement

```
{% if user.is_active %} <!-- checks if user signed in-->
<!-- Insert code here that appears if signed in-->
{% else%}
<!-- Insert code here to display for users that did not sign in-->
{% endif%}
```

Lastly the templates can be found [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates) if you need to style them. But you need to create an accounts folder and place them in there to override the default ones.